# How do I edit the title for right column in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am looking everywhere to change the title on the right column.

On my right column there is filter, compare product, newsletter, and some other things. But I just need to change "Compare Product" to "Compare". Just can't find the place where the string is.

I was looking everywhere on the web as well, all I can find is

> app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/*DEFAULT*/layout/

But the title bit is not found.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can change label of `"Compare Product" to "Compare"` 3 way

`1-Inline Translation`(For More info ([Click here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/))

```
2-Using CSV from app>locale>Your_Language_Pack(Ex-en_US)>Mage_Catalog.CSV
  around 191 Line you can find Compare Products 

3-Using template file from app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOURTHEME\template\catalog\product\compare\sidebar.phtml
```

you can find `<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Compare Products') ?>` around 34 line no

change to

```
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

It's in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml